# Boost doesn't seem to enable constexpr for std::numeric_limits with multiprecision types

Tags: c++, boost

I want to do some compile-time evaluation using boost multiprecision numbers.
Therefore I wrote some code, which does't compile properly.
I traced down the problem to this:

```
typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_oct test_t;
constexpr test_t nEps = std::numeric_limits<test_t>::epsilon();
```

which resulted in several error messages under MSVC 2017:

```
error C2127: 'nEps': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression
...\boost_1_75_0\boost\multiprecision\cpp_bin_float.hpp(1842): note: failure was because type 'test_t' is not a literal type
...\boost_1_75_0\boost\multiprecision\number.hpp(1982): note: type 'boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_bin_float<237,boost::multiprecision::backends::digit_base_2,void,int32_t,-262142,262143>,boost::multiprecision::et_off>' is not a literal type because its data member 'm_backend' is of non-literal type 'boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_bin_float<237,boost::multiprecision::backends::digit_base_2,void,int32_t,-262142,262143>'
...\boost_1_75_0\boost\multiprecision\cpp_bin_float.hpp(1842): note: type 'boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_bin_float<237,boost::multiprecision::backends::digit_base_2,void,int32_t,-262142,262143>' is not a literal type because it is not an aggregate type, a closure type, or does not have a constexpr constructor that is not a copy or move constructor
```

If I use `const` instead of `constexpr`, then the compiler works, but of course doesn't do compile-time evaluation, which is my target.
How can I overcome the issue? Maybe I have to use specific compiler settings or maybe boost isn't able to do compile-time evaluation with multiprecision types (I used boost v1.75.0)?

Comment: No `cpp_bin_float`'s constructors are `constexpr`, so you cannot have a `constexpr` `cpp_bin_float`... see [cpp_bin_float.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I there any alternative doing compile-time evaluation wtih multiprecision numbers? Or are there planned updates enabling this behaviour for boost?

Comment: C++20 might allow it, but Boost explicitly supports C++11 (many libraries including c++03, some limiting to C++14). I would guess it's not important enough in the context of Boost Multiprecision for now, and I imagine the ripple effects being enormous (not all standard libraries had constexpr-fied `<cmath>` last time I checked)